# Is there a safe, ergonomic way to change a phantom type in a complex struct?

Tags: rust, phantom-types

Suppose we define a generic struct, with many fields, representing a type-safe state machine using a phantom type:

```rust
struct Foo<State> {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C,
    //...
    state: PhantomData<State>,
}
```

We can then write a type-safe state transition:

```
impl Foo<SourceState> {
    fn transition(self, extra: X) -> Foo<DestinationState> {
        let Foo {a, b, c, state: _} = self;
        // do lots of stuff
        Foo { a, b, c, state: PhantomData } 
    }
}
```

But we need to awkwardly unpack every field and re-pack in in a different structure.

We could also use `mem::transmute`, although my understanding is that different monomorphizations of the same struct are not guaranteed to have the same memory layout.

I hoped that `Foo { state: PhantomData, ..self }` would work; alas, it fails to compile.

Is there any canonical, ergonomic, safe way to write this ?

Comment: If your state types are zero sized, you don't need a `PhantomData`, or maybe I didn't understand something

Comment: Please add the definition of `SourceState` and `DestinationState`

Comment: @Boiethios you are right, my state types in this case are unit types, but using PhantomData was shorter than implementing Default for all my states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in a straight forward manner, because they are 2 different types: that's the whole point of your code, actually. To simplify it, I'd do that in 2 steps, with a generic transition being the 2nd one:

```
use core::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<State> {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32,
    //...
    state: PhantomData<State>,
}

struct SourceState;
struct DestinationState;

impl<Src> Foo<Src> {
    fn transition<Dest>(self) -> Foo<Dest> {
        let Foo {a, b, c, state: _} = self;

        Foo { a, b, c, state: PhantomData } 
    }
}

impl Foo<SourceState> {
    fn to_destination_state(mut self, extra: ()) -> Foo<DestinationState> {
        // Do whatever you want with self

        self.transition()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can abstract the fact that you have a state:

```
mod stateful {
    use core::marker::PhantomData;

    pub struct Stateful<T, State> {
        pub data: T,
        state: PhantomData<State>,
    }

    impl<T, SrcState> Stateful<T, SrcState> {
        pub fn transform<DestState>(self) -> Stateful<T, DestState> {
            let Stateful { data, state: _ } = self;

            Stateful {
                data,
                state: Default::default(),
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Data {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32,
}

struct SourceState;
struct DestinationState;

type Foo<State> = stateful::Stateful<Data, State>;

impl Foo<SourceState> {
    fn to_destination_state(mut self, extra: ()) -> Foo<DestinationState> {
        // Do whatever you want with self.data

        self.transform()
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is what I ended up doing. A subsidiary question is: why does the struct ellipsis syntax require identity of types ? Could it desugar to a bunch of accesses and remove this constraint ? or would this break too much type inference in practice ?

Comment: So there's no way to do this without copying data?

Comment: @user1685095 What do you mean? There is not a single copy in my snippets.

Comment: @Boiethios You are copying data with "let Foo {a, b, c, state: _} = self;". This will not work with types which are not Copy.

Comment: @user1685095 The first solution doesn't fix the problem but provides an indirection. Since if you want to avoid copying the data, you still need to mutate the Phantom Type. Which is kinda the problem in the first place.

Comment: @OmarAbid No, there is no copy: `Foo` is not marked as `Copy`, so it is not copiable. In the snippet you write, `self` is moved.
The first solution allows you to write the code only once, even if you have dozens of states, that's why I included it.